# Create a jar file for application to run

Tags: java, jar

I have two projects, one which generates messages and sends them to the server via socket connection, and another project which sits server side, and consumes the messages and sends them to a queue. Is there anyway, rather than start the sender project first then start my server side project, export the first to a jar file and then somehow invoke the jar file and get it to start sending?

Thanks

Comment: Surely you would normally want to start the *server-side project* first, anyway?

Comment: Well, I guess the ordering is not that important , its just more of finding a way of incorportaing the two projects in a way which doesnt require me to manually right click in eclipse and run as java application

Comment: So are expecting a code to invoke the jar file or you want to know how to create a jar file ?

Comment: No, i was wondering how to invoke the jar file but i think it is via process builder now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to invoke your jar file through code this is it -

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c java -jar another.jar");
```